# Add custom message to knockout required validation

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have added a required validation to my observable. How can I change the message to something other than "This field is required."

```
self.Leaving = ko.observable(leaving).extend({
    required:   {
        onlyIf: function() { return self.Status() == 10; }
    }              
});
```

Comment: Their website clearly mentions how to do this... https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
self.Leaving = ko.observable(leaving).extend({
    required:   {
        onlyIf: function() { return self.Status() == 10; },
        message: 'Custom message'
    }
});
```